# How do we deploy a smart contract with Oraclize to Rinkeby Network?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, oracles

I have created a smart contract with Oraclize logic which I tested locally using Truffle.
Now I want to test it on Rinkeby network along with my front end, what it the process to do so ?

How do we generate the OAR OraclizeAddrResolverI that we have to mention inside contract constructor for Rinkeby Network?

Comment: I believe you only need UsingOraclize contract deployed yourself on Rinkeby, it will resolve other Oraclize contracts.

Comment: Thanks @Maxpeinas for your reply. My dapp also has a front-end and offchain mongodb (using mLab) server. How can launch this entire setup along with smart contract to make dapp available to the world, are there any preferred options in these cases ?

Comment: Just import oraclize into contract the same way as you do in your local node and everything should work, unless i'm missing the question here.